# Checking If 2 Numbers are Multiples

Tags: vbscript

I need a way to check if two different numbers are multiples of each other using VB Script. So 2 and 4 would return a yes or positive but 2 and 5 would return a no or negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `Mod`:

```
If int1 Mod int2 = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo int1 & " is a multiple of " & int2
End If
```

---

**Edit:**

If you want to test if *either* is a multiple of the other:

```
If int1 Mod int2 = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo int1 & " is a multiple of " & int2
ElseIf int2 Mod int1 = 0 Then 
    WScript.Echo int2 & " is a multiple of " & int1
Else
    WScript.Echo "Neither " & int1 & " nor " & int2 & " is a multiple of the other."
End If
```

---

**Edit 2:**

Per @Ansgar's suggestion below, if you just need to know whether one is a multiple of the other but don't care to know which, here's a function that simply returns a boolean value:

```
Function TestMultiple(int1, int2) 
    TestMultiple = (int1 Mod int2 = 0) Or (int2 Mod int1 = 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Since he wants to return a boolean value I'd encapsulate that in a function, e.g. like this: `Function TestMultiple(int1, int2) : TestMultiple = (int1 Mod int2 = 0) Or (int2 Mod int1 = 0) : End Function`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I've updated the answer to include your function. Thanks for the suggestion.